# How do I pickle wood plugs for inoculation?

Tags: mushrooms, growing-medium

I've heard from a world famous mycologist that you should pickle your wood plugs prior to inoculation. What solution should I use to pickle them?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the claim?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LcVDVXYrCG4

Answer (score 3):

He's talking about pasteurizing wood chips or straw using immersion in water to create an anaerobic environment to kill off the aerobic bacteria and fungi.  Then he removes the water to expose the wood chips to air and inoculates them with mycelium.  With no aerobic competitors, the mycelium then runs rapidly.  This is a known method of pasteurizing without the need for heat.

Wooden dowels are much more compact, and it's easier to just boil them to sterilize them.

Comment: how do i use this method?

Comment: Boil for 30 mins, cool, let them dry, and use.

Comment: that's the anaerobic method?

Comment: No,  the anaerobic method is in my answer.

Comment: how do you get them to go anaerobic?

Comment: submerse them in the water and leave for 2 weeks.

Comment: how do i create the desired bacteria environments?

Comment: Just double-checking: have you looked up what “anaerobic” and “aerobic” means?